# is it possible to use udp_sendto to resend an UDP packet?

Tags: c, lwip

I have this code

Only as example to show the intention of resending some info (retry)

```
static char server_req [] = "INIT_PREVIEW";

static void
halt_task ( void )
{
    while ( true )
        ;
}
void
tst_task ( Tst_struct * tst_p )
{
    struct udp_pcb  *   my_udp  = NULL;
    struct pbuf     *   p       = NULL;
    ip4_addr_t          server_ip;

    // Wait 3 seconds for everything to start
    vTaskDelay ( pdMS_TO_TICKS ( 3000 ) );

    // Creates udp
    if ( (my_udp = udp_new ()) == NULL )
        halt_task ();

    udp_bind  ( my_udp, IP_ADDR_ANY, 10000 );

    if ( (p = pbuf_alloc ( PBUF_TRANSPORT, sizeof ( server_req ), PBUF_RAM )) == NULL )
        halt_task ();

    inet_aton ( "195.168.1.90", & server_ip );

    memcpy ( p->payload, server_req, sizeof ( server_req ) );

    for ( int tries = 1 ; tries <= 3 ; tries ++ ) {
        udp_sendto  ( my_udp, p, & server_ip, 10000 );
        vTaskDelay  ( pdMS_TO_TICKS ( 500 ) );
    }

    halt_task ();
}
```

here is wireshark output

[image: first packet]

[image: second packet]

as it can be seen:

- not sent 3 times but only 2
- 2nd time it sends more (garbage) data

any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: This code does not compile and only tries to read once. Please post a minimal, reproducible example that we can put into files and run for our selves.

Comment: Hi Fredrik
Yes, I cut a lot of code no relevant to the question
OK, I will make a compilable code
Thank you very much

Comment: Fredrik: I wrote, compiled an example and show wireshark output too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that in your case you're using `lwIP` library, but more in general it is quite easy to "resend" a UDP packet (and that should apply to `lwIP` too):

```c
void test(void) {
  int sockfd = init_socket_somehow();
  bind_socket_somehow(sockfd);

  // example loop that resends packets the same way they are received:
  while (1) {
    struct sockaddr sender; // this will store info about the sender
    socklen_t sender_size; // this will store sender address' size

    uint8_t buff[500]; // this will store the UDP packet contents
    size_t buff_size; // this will store buff's size

    ssize_t bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buff, 500, 0, &sender, &sender_size);

    if (bytes > 0) {
      buff_size = (size_t) bytes;

      // we have received some data via UDP, now we will resend the same data back to the sender
      sendto(sockfd, buff, buff_size, 0, &sender, sender_size);
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: take this snippet more like pseudocode (it just shows the logic; no error checks are made); you can adapt it in order to use it in your program.

EDIT:

The previous snippet resends received packets, which is not what you asked, so this following snippet can be used to resend the same packet more than once:

```c
// send packet "packet" three times
uint8_t packet[100]; // fill the packet with some content to send
struct sockaddr dest = ...; // get the destination address and port somehow
socklen_t dest_size = ...; // and also the destination address' size

for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  sendto(sockfd, packet, 100, 0, &dest, dest_size);
}
```

I've looked around on the Internet and, as you already noted in your answer, the `lwIP` library behaves quite strangely in some cases.

But I also found out that `lwIP` supports a BSD socket interface (i.e.: the same functions that I used in my code snippets and that are widely used on Linux and other OSes: `socket()`, `bind()`, `recvfrom()`, `sendto()`, etc.), so my suggestion is to use the BSD socket functions when using the `lwIP` library in order to have a (hopefully) more predictable behavior.

This [link](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/lwip.html) should help you using BSD socket API with `lwIP` library.

Comment: Thank you Luca
I'm not sure if I understand correctly
but I'm trying to resend (retry) some info
(and not to resend **received** info)

Comment: I corrected my answer's code snippet, plus I added a suggestion for how to use `lwIP` library with a more "predictable" behavior (i.e.: use BSD socket API). I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very very much, Luca
I'm used to use this API because it is not blocking (and I don't like to be blocked :-)
But perhaps you're right, I should consider to use BSD socket interface
I really appreciate your advice

Comment: I don't know about BSD socket API of `lwIP` library, but on Linux the BSD socket API can also be non-blocking (e.g.: `recvfrom()` doesn't block if there are no packets to receive), or you can also set a timeout (e.g.: block `recvfrom()` for max 2 seconds). Depending on the target platform (Linux, bare-metal microcontroller, FreeRTOS, Windows, ecc.) and on the purpose of the program (what the program should do), one can study an optimal approach to UDP server/client implementation (blocking vs. non-blocking, multi-threaded, ecc.).

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer did help you, you can mark it as accepted answer. If you have problems with non-blocking BSD sockets etc., you can open a new targeted question.

Comment: sorry, I don't know well how this works
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at source code of lwip library, udp.c file
"It seems" that, udp_send (which calls to udp_sendto) increases the payload for adding headers, so it can not be called again, expecting that same content will be sent.
To me is strange that implementation and/or there's no other way to retry (which is common necessity of connection less protocol as UDP)
Anyway, I will appreciate any comment that adds information.

Comment: LWIP is meant to be light weight. That means as little copying as possible and lots of "inplace" stuff. The Linux kernel has top copy your userdata into the UDP buffer on the "send" call. This copy is optimized away by allowing you to build your packet inside the buffer that UDP send can use. As "resend the same data" is rare, it is more efficient for you to rebuild the data in the buffer than to "always copy" when in 99% of the cases that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to resend a packet if you restore the state of the pbuf after the send function from LWIP.

struct pbuf pbuf_saved;

pbuf_saved = *p;

This is needed once only if you keep the PBUF.

Then

udp_sendto....
*p = pbuf_saved;

That will restore the header state of the pbuf.
During allocation there is headroom reserved for all protocol and hardware layers which leeds to modification of the length variables and the payload buffer.
Of course you might update the vars selectively, but the upper way is the most easiest.
Alternatively you could use the direct way of sending via the interface calls, but this might not be as good as if ARP didn't resolve you might get no new ARP resolution.